# Usage of 'be to' like "is to"

Tags: grammar, to-infinitive

> They have something a bit different, which **is to** think up an idea
> for a five-minute movie and then film it, using special animation
> software.
>
> — Cambridge IELTS 16 Listening Test 01

I don't know what kind of grammar is used in bold text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no meaning to "is to".
You should look at the meaning like this :: "which is" & "to think up" ;; not like "is to".

> They have something a bit **different**, ...
> ... **which is**
> ...... **to think up** an idea
> ......... for a five-minute movie
> ...... and then film it,
> ......... using special animation software.